# Unexpected T_CLONE using Math_Matrix PEAR library

Tags: php, matrix, pear

I've not used PEAR before, and so I'm probably doing something dumb. I've installed the Math_Matrix library, but when I include it I just get an error. My entire code is this:

```
<?php
  $path = '/home/PEAR/Math_Matrix-0.8.0';
  set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
  include_once 'Matrix.php';
?>
```

The error I get is this:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLONE, expecting T_STRING in /home/PEAR/Math_Matrix-0.8.0/Matrix.php on line 272
```

I'm not really sure what to make of that. I guess the explanations I can think of are:

1. I've not installed the Math_Matrix library properly (I'm on a shared server which already had PEAR installed on it) or have downloaded the wrong version of it.
2. I'm supposed to include something else before I include Matrix.php
3. I've included the wrong file (or the right filename but with the wrong path, somehow).

To install it, I did the following:

```
pear install --alldeps channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
pear install --alldeps channel://pear.php.net/Math_Vector-0.6.2
pear install Math_Matrix
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Math_Matrix](http://pear.php.net/package/Math_Matrix homepage) I can see that it was last updated in 2003.  Since then, PHP has added the [`clone` keyword](http://www.php.net/clone), which is conflicting with the `clone()` function defined in Matrix.php.

You need to update Matrix.php - a search & replace on "clone" with "clone2" should do it.